# Append files with bash one-liner?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

Currently I use multiple lines to append content into a combined file, e.g.

```
./myprogram 1.txt > Out.txt # Overwrite for the 1st file
./myprogram 2.txt >> Out.txt
./myprogram 3.txt >> Out.txt
./myprogram 4.txt >> Out.txt
```

Is it possible to replace by one-liner?

Comment: I will never understand why people insist on magical *one liners* instead of putting an easy to understand solution into a shell script.

Comment: Because it is error prone, the first line is a single ">", and the rest of lines are ">>", I've several times used ">>" in the first line due to copy and paste, so I am looking for more elegant solution. does it make sense to you?

Comment: Creating a shell script with good formatting, indentation and comments is better anyway because it's easier to understand, and therefore *less* error prone then an endless one-liner. If you need to do the above more than once, it will also save a lot of time.

Comment: @Ryan you could begin with `cat /dev/null > Out.txt` and have `>>` on all invocations of `./myprogram`.

Answer (score 8):

```
(./myprogram 1.txt; ./myprogram 2.txt; ./myprogram 3.txt; ./myprogram 4.txt) > out.txt
```

Comment: +1 Bonus, this works in bash, sh, csh/tcsh, zsh, and probably more...

Answer (score 5):

It depends on what you want to do and how your program handle input args.

But let's say you have `/path/to/myprogram.sh` who look like this one :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Processing file ${1?missing input file}"
```

You could do the following

```
find /path/to/inputfiles -name "*.txt" -exec /path/to/myprogram.sh {} \; > Out.txt
```

Or within bash (or any Bourne-like shell):

```
for i in *.txt; do /path/to/myprogram.sh "$i"; done > Out.txt
```

*(I use for-loop or find because it will be much more convenient if you have 1000 input files instead of the 4 files in your example)*

Comment: careful with the `*.txt` if `Out.txt` already exists.

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to Per's answer, but maintains the layout of the original:

```
{
    ./myprogram 1.txt
    ./myprogram 2.txt
    ./myprogram 3.txt
    ./myprogram 4.txt
} > Out.txt
```

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping

Answer (score 0):

myprogram-wrapper.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh -
while test $# -ge 1
do
  ./myprogram $1
  shift
done
```

invoke with `./myprogram-wrapper.sh 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt 4.txt > Out.txt`

To make a reusable wrapper:

```
#!/bin/sh -
prog=$1
shift
while test $# -ge 1
do
  ${prog} $1
  shift
done
```

and invoke like `wrapper ./mycommand 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt 4.txt > Out.txt`

This is of course cheating, since the script itself is not a oneliner, but I thought you might like it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I find this solution more elegant:

```
FILE=/tmp/file.log

exec >> $FILE
./myprogram 1.txt
./myprogram 2.txt
./myprogram 3.txt
./myprogram 4.txt
exec 1<&2

echo 'Normal output has returned!'
```